# Howto supress MVC information messages in logger?

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I use the default logging function in combination with serilog to write logging info to a file. It works, but I can't work out how to suppress all the informational messages (mainly MVC). I tried a number of options, added Logging.Filter but no result... I'm using VS2015 and IIS-Express.

```
Logger output: 
2016-06-16 19:34:52.984 +02:00 [Information] HttpContext.User merged via     AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: "Identity.Application".
2016-06-16 19:34:52.993 +02:00 [Information] Executing action method     "Test.Controllers.SurveysController.Create (Test)" with arguments (["Test.Survey"]) -     ModelState is Invalid'
2016-06-16 19:34:53.027 +02:00 [Error] this is the error I want to show in     "SurveysController"
System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at Test.Controllers.SurveysController.<Create>d__7.MoveNext() in     C:\Users\dummy\Documents\Visual Studio     2015\Projects\Test\src\Test\Controllers\SurveysController.cs:line 97
2016-06-16 19:34:53.061 +02:00 [Information] Executing ViewResult, running view at     path "/Views/Surveys/Create.cshtml".
2016-06-16 19:34:53.083 +02:00 [Information] Executed action     "Test.Controllers.SurveysController.Create (Test)" in 94.1372ms
2016-06-16 19:34:53.087 +02:00 [Information] Request finished in 111.506ms 200     text/html; charset=utf-8

Startup.cs:
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,     ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Debug);

            //extra package installed to try and filter logging
            loggerFactory.WithFilter(new FilterLoggerSettings
            {
                { "Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning },
                { "System", LogLevel.Warning },
                { "Test", LogLevel.Information }
            });

appsettings.json:
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",       // information => error
      "System": "Error",        // information => error
      "Microsoft": "Error"      // information => error
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

The thing is `WithFilter` extension returns a wrapped logger factory and you would need to add the providers like `Serilog`, `Console` etc. on it to take effect.

Example:

```
    //extra package installed to try and filter logging
    loggerFactory = loggerFactory.WithFilter(new FilterLoggerSettings
    {
        { "Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning },
        { "System", LogLevel.Warning },
        { "Test", LogLevel.Information }
    });

    loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Debug);
```

If you would like to just disable receive Warning level MVC's log messages, you should be able to use the filer like `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": LogLevel.Warning`

Comment: Forgot that serilog logger was created in Startup constructor and minimumlevel is fulle controlled from there.
Still not able to filter out mvc messages btw.

Startup:
`Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()`  
`.WriteTo.RollingFile("logs\\testlog-{Date}.txt")`  
`.MinimumLevel.Information()`  
`.CreateLogger();`

Comment: .WithFilter requires yet another package:
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter": "1.0.0",

Comment: Soon you will be able to read these filters from appsetting.json, per this link [https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/437]

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to pull in the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter nuget package.  I pulled in the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging nuget but didn't know that I also needed Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter nuget.